# Wifi will not work

Tags: iwlwifi

I am very new to Ubuntu and I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Dell Inc. Inspiron N5010.  The wifi will not work and shows as disabled. After looking for fixes on the internet, I could not understand what to do. Any help would be appreciated,

I have ran the `sudo lshw -c network` command in terminal with the following result:

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
       logical name: wlp18s0
       version: 00
       serial: 8c:a9:82:27:7c:aa
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-41-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:fbc00000-fbc01fff

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no 

$ sudo dmesg | grep wlp    
[   20.307389] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0 wlp18s0: renamed from wlan0

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
If I paste this, it pushes the post over the character limit. 

First few lines show this:

[   19.285385] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[   20.237640] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   20.237646] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   20.237647] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   20.237649] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   20.275004] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   20.307389] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0 wlp18s0: renamed from wlan0
[   41.572037] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
[   41.580049] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
[   41.580065] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode

Last few lines show :

[ 1143.141562] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 3 entries
[ 1143.141582] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000000:0x0000028c:0117
[ 1143.141595] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000021:0x00000000:1208
[ 1143.141608] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000302:0x00000000:0125
[ 1143.153929] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 1143.153957] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
```

`$ mdsum /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode`

```
9f81a060ed274f76cd605295da77f7a6 /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138082/discussion-on-question-by-brian-wifi-will-not-work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set NetworkingEnabled true in  NetworkManager.state file. Follow the below steps,

```
sudo service NetworkManager stop
```

Then, open /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state with sudo user.

Change NetworkingEnabled=false To NetworkingEnabled=true and save the file.

Now restart the network-manager service.

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Comment: It gave me an error message when trying to stop network-manager. The error message read "Failed to stop network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not loaded."

Comment: Also, I opened the network-manager.state file and NetworkingEnabled was already set as true.

Comment: I believe the service name is NetworkManager. I suggest that you correct your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First,go to Additional Drivers. A driver for your network card should show up. Go ahead and install it. I had this problem too and it worked for me.

Comment: I get "No additional drivers" when I check for additional drivers.